# SQL Server return sequence next value as view column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a Collection of MS SQL Server sequences and want to return the name, current value and next value of the sequences as the columns of a view, hence increasing a sequence each time it is contained in a result, how do I define the view?

```
select * from SEQUENCE_VIEW

NAME        CURRVALL NEXTVAL
SEQUENCE1   0        1
SEQUENCE2   1        2
```

I was able to retrieve name and currentvalue from sys.sequences, but failed to include something like NEXT VALUE FOR NAME in the view definition.

EDIT
For those wondering why someone should do something like this, this mechanism is used by an internal ORMapper, not relying on identity columns or similar mechanisms present in the underlying database engine to generate ids for entries.

Comment: So your goal is to actually increment the value or just show what it would be?

Comment: `but failed to include` - good. stop right there and rethink what you actually need and how you are trying to approach this.

Comment: I want to increase the value

Answer (score -1):

```
Create view SEQUENCE_VIEW as
  SELECT NAME
       , current_value as CURRVALL
       , current_value + increment as NEXTVAL
  FROM sys.sequences
```

Comment: But this will not increase the sequence, hence giving the same value for multiple selects.